# Using boto3 to update a cloudformation template

Tags: python, boto3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use boto3 to update an existing CloudFormation template, but my code fails on the 'Parameters' property! Here is what I have tried:

1. Read params from a config file

   ```
   from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser  
   parser = SafeConfigParser()  
   parser.optionxform=str  
   parser.read( '/parms/SecGrpsParams.cfg')  
   parms = dict(parser.items('params'))
   ```

print parms" produces

> {'Application': 'Click2Buy', 'AdminCidr': '10.0.0.0/8', 'AppMoniker': 'c2b', 'vId': 'vpc-3bec005f'}

2. Call update_stack

   ```
   client = boto3.client('cloudformation')  
   response = client.update_stack(  
       StackName = args.stackname,  
       TemplateURL = template,  
       Parameters = args.params,  
       Capabilities = ['CAPABILITY_IAM']  
    )
   ```
3. And the code produces this error:
   botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
   Invalid type for parameter Parameters,
   value: {'Application': 'Click2Buy', 'AdminCidr': '10.0.0.0/8', 'AppMoniker': 'c2b', 'vId': 'vpc-3bec005f'},
   type: type: , valid types: ,

I have tried to `args.params.items()`, `[args.params]`, and `[args.params.items()]` but can't figure out what is needed.

Answer (score 5):

I've discovered the problem with my pervious attempts. The "update_stack" call wants a list object passed to the 'Parameters' field in the form of `Parameters = [{'ParameterKey':"parm_name", "ParameterValue":'parm_value'}].` And, the number of passed parameters must be an exact match of the Parameters definition in the CloudFormation template in number and syntax.